# Custom 404 shows "File not found" for php files instead of redirecting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, vps

I'm trying to create a custom 404 error page.

What I have so far works very well with all unexisting documents, folders, images, htmls, etc. - opens my custom 404 page (with output **Custom 404!**)

However, when I try to access a file with a `.php` extension that does not exist I get this:

[image: 404 response]

...being a "**File not found.**" on the screen, rather than being redirected to my 404 document.

*My .htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

*My 404.php*

```
<?php

header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
include '404.html';
die();

?>
```

*My 404.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Custom 404 | Not found!</title>
</head>
<body>

Custom 404!

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

To be more clear about what is happening here.

I believe paths and .htaccess work just fine but there has to be some trick with php. Here are few examples:

When I try to open some files that do not exist on my server:

- myurl.com/folderthatdoesntexist/ -> opens correct 404 / echoes Custom
  404!
- myurl.com/imagethatdoesntexist.jpg -> opens correct 404 / echoes
  Custom 404!
- myurl.com/htmlthatdoesntexist.html -> opens correct 404 / echoes
  Custom 404!
- myurl.com/phpthatdoesntexist.php -> DOES NOT open correct 404 -> says
  **file not found**

Comment: It says "ErrorDocument 404 /404.php" but the 404 page is a HTML file? Something's wrong. Why not: `ErrorDocument 404 /404`

Comment: @user770 What exactly isn't right about that? He's redirecting the error page to 404.php and the php file includes 404.html. I agree it's a bit of a strange approach but I wouldn't say it's technically wrong.

Comment: You state *"works very well with all the unexisting documents"* - but then *"when i try to open php file that does not exist"* - I'm confused. Which php file are you trying to open? Plus, are you sure the path is correct? You may need to use a full server address. Is this run locally or hosted?

Comment: Right! He's missing this: `include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."full/path/to/404.html");`

Comment: @user770 if your comment was to respond to icecub, you need to `@icecub` them as they did for you.

Comment: It was to you actually, but I thought users get notified once they comment on a post? I guess not, whoops! Ty @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: @user770 only the OP gets notified and of all comments, pinged or not. When other members comment to each other, then a direct ping is required.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I usually tend to keep an eye on comments I've replied to for a while so no worries :) As for OP's issue, I'd suggest replacing `include '404.html';` with `echo "Error works";` to verify that the redirect is working. If so, the issue is that 404.html can't be found like @user770 says. If not, the issue lies in htaccess.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner True. Though sometimes you don't know "why" an OP isn't responding. Could be internet down or some emergency. So I don't see a lack of response as disrepect. More just a reason to move on.

Comment: Where are the two files located: 404.php and 404.html and post some examles of URLs that work and some that don't - testing on my local apache server looks like it works fine with regular files and php file requests.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner it is hosted (digitalocean with serverpilot), both files are inside root (public), also .htaccess, like i said it shows the correct 404 page with all "not found" files except with php extensions

Comment: @icecub i tried with echoing something, no difference. It echoes correct with all files/folders except with php extensions..

Comment: added edit to be more clear what is happening

Comment: *Morning* @BikerJohn Ok, guess what? I too am facing the same problem on one of my hosted servers and I never knew I did have that same problem to begin with. I just sent a note to them asking them why that is. If I get back any relevant information with either a fix or explanation, I'll let you know. Have a look through https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/urlmapping.html#notfound also in the meantime and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/custom-error.html.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner hey, actually i have vps hosting, not shared one, so i have root access to everything but dont know exactly how to deal with this problem. I will go through your links, and yes please let me know if you find out any good information :)

Comment: @BikerJohn I have a funny feeling that the host the site's on I told you about, won't be answering me back anytime soon. See what you can find out on your side and ask them for support. I am pretty sure they'll shed some light on this, should your service have better support/communication skills. If you do get your solution (from them); please post an answer for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect the difference is that php files launch the interpreter while html files are just served.  A solution that works but might not be the only one or the best one is to add this directive to the host configuration file:

```
ProxyErrorOverride on
```

Answer (score 7):

This happens because you might've enabled the mod_proxy_fcgi and you are using PHP-FPM. The default error page in the proxy is `File not found`. So add the following to your httpd.conf or apache2.conf, not to your .htaccess.

It makes your .htaccess file's `ErrorDocument` directive to override the default Proxy error page.

```
ProxyErrorOverride On
```

Thanks.